# Can I add a WordPress page without installing WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a project and my bosses for some reason want us to add a WordPress webpage they have for a landing page. The rest of the website is actually coded. 
What they've made in WordPress is just a landing page. Is there any way to add that easily without installing all WordPress, making a new DB, etcetera, etcetera? 
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: just copy-paste the HTML source code of the page and make it static. I can't think of any other way to do that w/o having the full core running. Just make sure the css/js links are available and you should be good to go

Comment: ^ This is the way.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately You can't because Wordpress is created based on all page and post data saved on SQL and for creating a custom template you're referring to a page in your code or just choosing template from the pages tools like this

```
<?php /* Template Name: Example Template */ ?>
```